# Read Avro and parse from web

Tags: python, avro

I used `urllib2` to get an avro file into my variable "myavro".

How do I read it into the Python Avro library?

I have tried the following:

```
a = urllib2.urlopen(url)
myavro = a.read()
reader = DataFileReader(open(myavro, "r"), DatumReader())
```

Comment: Which error does it return (raise)?

Comment: You can save data downloaded with `urllib2` in `StringIO` and read it!

Comment: @ForceBru Updated OP. Note that I can save the file at that URL, and use the DataFileReader without any problems.

Comment: Try `StringIO(a.read()).read()`

Comment: This seems to return the original error I got before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wants bytes not a str. Try:

```
from io import BytesIO
a = urllib2.urlopen(url)
myavro = a.read()
reader = DataFileReader(BytesIO(myavro), DatumReader())
```